# RazorPay form auto load on page load without clicking Pay Now button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay in my application. Here is a code that controls loading of payment model when "Pay Now" button is clicked. I want to make the modal load on page load instead of button click. I tried submitting form via javascript to see if that loads the modal but that's not working.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST" id="gateway">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<?php echo $data['key']?>"
    data-amount="<?php echo $data['amount']?>"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-name="<?php echo $data['name']?>"
    data-image="<?php echo $data['image']?>"
    data-description="<?php echo $data['description']?>"
    data-prefill.name="<?php echo $data['prefill']['name']?>"
    data-prefill.email="<?php echo $data['prefill']['email']?>"
    data-prefill.contact="<?php echo $data['prefill']['contact']?>"
    data-notes.shopping_order_id="3456"
    data-order_id="<?php echo $data['order_id']?>"
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_amount="<?php echo $data['display_amount']?>" <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_currency="<?php echo $data['display_currency']?>" <?php } ?>
  >
    document.getElementById("gateway").submit(); // Not working
  </script>
  <!-- Any extra fields to be submitted with the form but not sent to Razorpay -->
  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_order_id" value="3456">
</form>
```

However, I also noticed that form actions to page `verify.php` so if the form is submitted it will go to that page where I just want to load the payment modal. Hence, what I tried can just not be the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Posting as it may be of help for someone in the future:

In `razorpay/checkout/automatic.php (or manual.php)` place this right after the opening `<form>` element:

```
<script>
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.razorpay-payment-button').click();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: where did you get the file: razorpay/checkout/automatic.php (or manual.php) from?

Answer (score 2):

Attach an onload event to script and simulate click in the handler

```
<script>
  function loadPaymentModal() {
    const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('razorpay-payment-button')[0];
    elem.click();
  }
</script>
<form action="verify.php" method="POST" id="gateway">
  <script onLoad="loadPaymentModal()" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<?php echo $data['key']?>" 
    data-amount="<?php echo $data['amount']?>" 
    data-currency="INR"
    data-name="<?php echo $data['name']?>"
    data-image="<?php echo $data['image']?>"
    data-description="<?php echo $data['description']?>" 
    data-prefill.name="<?php echo $data['prefill']['name']?>"
    data-prefill.email="<?php echo $data['prefill']['email']?>"
    data-prefill.contact="<?php echo $data['prefill']['contact']?>" 
    data-notes.shopping_order_id="3456"
    data-order_id="<?php echo $data['order_id']?>"
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !=='INR' ) { ?> data - display_amount="<?php echo $data['display_amount']?>" <? php } ?>
    <? php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data - display_currency="<?php echo $data['display_currency']?>" <? php } ?>
  >
    </script>
  <!-- Any extra fields to be submitted with the form but not sent to Razorpay -->
  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_order_id" value="3456">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="{{url('/')}}/frontendtheme/js/plugins/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        jQuery('#gateway').submit();
    });
</script>
```

**note: Use your min.js file folder on script source**